# Disable exception trapping on dojo datagrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

When a DataGrid is rendering, if it encounters an error along the way (in my case, often with cell.formatter or cell.get,) the grid catches the exception, aborts the entire process, and simple puts the vague message, "Sorry, an error occurred".

Is there a way to suppress that exception trapping so that when an error occurs, it appears in the debugging console?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do this with dojo's default behavior, so as a workaround I made a small utility to change the layout structure before I passed it to the grid. (Kind of a hack, but I made the grid in script, not with markup, so it works for now, and a new grid is on the drawing board anyway....

```
lib.wrapTryCatch = function(call, onException){
    onException = onException || function(e){ 
            console.log({wrappedException: e});
            return e.message;
        };

    var f =  function tryWrapper(){
        try{
            var val = call.apply(this, arguments);
            return val;
        }
        catch(e){
            return onException(e);
        }
    }
    f.wrapped = call;
    f.onException = onException;
    return f;
}

lib.gridUtils = {

    /** Convenience/debugging function to make exceptions visible 
     *  if grid structure cells have errors.
     *  
     *  Puts exception to the console, instead of the grid's default
     *  behavior of dying silently 
     *  
     * */
     decorateStructure: function(structure){

            for(var idx in structure){
                cell = structure[idx];

                if('get' in cell){
                    cell.get = lib.wrapTryCatch(cell.get);
                }

                if('formatter' in cell){
                    cell.formatter = lib.wrapTryCatch(cell.formatter);
                }

            }
            return structure;
        }
}
```